# Using INotifyPropertyChanged and commands c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried to use INotifyPropertyChanged interface but unfortunately it didnt connect with main ui.

```
// Declare the event
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private int _counter;

public int Counter
{
    get { return _counter; }
    set
    {
        _counter = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}


protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private ICommand _clickCommand;
public ICommand ClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _clickCommand ?? (_clickCommand = new CommandHandler(() => MyAction(), () => CanExecute));
    }
}
public bool CanExecute
{
    get
    {
        // check if executing is allowed, i.e., validate, check if a process is running, etc. 
        return true;
    }
}

public void MyAction()
{
    Counter++;
}
```

.xaml file

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:viewmodel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Counter}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

My idea is when i click button => should add 1 to counter.But  ui doesnt update.
I dont know how to update ui using command and INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: your code looks good to me.

Comment: yes but label dont update at all

Comment: I see, I will post the answer.

Comment: @dbvega ok nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewmodel` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
...
public class viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
...
```

Keep the rest of your code as is.